# Is it natural to say “mon Français”?

Tags: formulation-idiomatique

In English you might say “my Spanish is not very good,” in reference to your language skills, or “I’m trying to improve my Japanese.” Is the same true in French?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, we definitely use the same phrasing.

Beware that there is no capital in language names in French:

> *Mon espagnol n'est pas très bon.*
>
> *J'essaie d'améliorer mon japonais.*

Comment: Ah, i knew that, just wasn't paying enough attention. Thank you!

Comment: Of course, one's French husband (mon Français) might need improvement too ;)

Comment: @Luke L'Espagnol de ma Française n'a pas un bon allemand...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can say it, but this is, in my opinion, not the best option.

I personally never heard "mon" before a language! I would use "en":

> Je ne suis pas très bon en espagnol
>
> J'essaye de m'améliorer en japonais

Literally, your language is not improving, but you are improving in language.

Comment: Pourtant, « Mon français » ou « Mon espagnol » etc. est très courant.

Comment: Je n'ai pourtant jamais entendu ça ailleurs des traductions mot-à-mot ! "Mon niveau d'espagnol" est beaucoup plus français, selon moi.